# Many errors on yum upgrade/update?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade, software-updates

When I launch yum update or yum upgrade on my CentOS 7 machine i get many errors:

```
[root@ns3269383 ~]# yum update
Plugin abilitati:fastestmirror, langpacks, protectbase
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fr.mirror.babylon.network
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Risoluzione dipendenze
--> Esecuzione del controllo di transazione
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.1.0-2.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.1.0-2.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) per il pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.4.0-6.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libmspack.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.4.0-6.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-0.11.b1.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.0.1-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Esecuzione del controllo di transazione
---> Pacchetto libmspack.x86_64 0:0.5-0.1.alpha.el6 settato per essere installato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python-clibs.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere installato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) per il pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Risoluzione delle dipendenze completata
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: libwebp-0.3.0-3.el7.x86_64 (installed)
                libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libconfig.so.8()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
 Si può provare ad usare --skip-broken per aggirare il problema
 Provare ad eseguire: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Same happens with yum upgrade

```
[root@ns3269383 ~]# yum upgrade    
Plugin abilitati:fastestmirror, langpacks, protectbase
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fr.mirror.babylon.network
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Risoluzione dipendenze
--> Esecuzione del controllo di transazione
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.1.0-2.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.1.0-2.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) per il pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.4.0-6.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libmspack.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.4.0-6.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-0.11.b1.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.0.1-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Esecuzione del controllo di transazione
---> Pacchetto libmspack.x86_64 0:0.5-0.1.alpha.el6 settato per essere installato
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libconfig.so.8()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto libstoragemgmt-python-clibs.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 settato per essere installato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libyajl.so.1()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libudev.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.0-3.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-4.el7 settato per essere aggiornato
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libnettle.so.4()(64bit) per il pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Pacchetto nettle.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) per il pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto open-vm-tools-desktop.x86_64 0:9.10.2-3.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) per il pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64
---> Pacchetto pyusb.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: python(abi) = 2.6 per il pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Pacchetto qpdf-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.1-2.el6 settato per essere un aggiornamento
--> Elaborazione dipendenza: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) per il pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Risoluzione delle dipendenze completata
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libproc-3.2.8.so()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: qpdf-libs-5.1.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libproc-3.2.8.so(_3_2_5)(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-dane-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: webkitgtk3-2.0.4-6.el7_0.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: libwebp-0.3.0-3.el7.x86_64 (installed)
                libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-utils-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (installed)
            Richiede: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libconfig.so.8()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: pyusb-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
            Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
            Installato: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
            Disponibile: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                python(abi) = 2.7
                python(abi) = 2.7
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libyajl.so.1()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: open-vm-tools-desktop-9.10.2-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
            Richiede: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Errore: Pacchetto: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
            Richiede: libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Rimozione in corso: nettle-2.7.1-4.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
            Aggiornato da: nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)
            Disponibile: nettle-2.7.1-2.el7.x86_64 (C7.0.1406-base)
                libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
 Si può provare ad usare --skip-broken per aggirare il problema
 Provare ad eseguire: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Why this happens? How I can fix it?

Comment: Please translate those error messages so we can actually help you

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to be sure without a proper translation, but I would guess that you have the CentOS6 EPEL repo set up on a CentOS7 system.

```
Errore: Pacchetto: libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.3.2-1.**el6**.x86_64 (epel)
        Richiede: python(abi) = 2.6
        Installato: python-2.7.5-18.**el7**_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
```

Notice how the update is asking for something from an epel repository with an 'el6' while you've got packages installed with 'el7'?  That's a good sign you've messed up and put the wrong EPEL on the system.  You should get rid of the existing epel repository and run `yum install epel-release` to install the correct repos.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with netistall in italian.
I resolved just doing:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with netinstall in italian. 
I resolved just doing:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```